# ESB Toolkit Error message

Tags: biztalk, esb, biztalk-2010, toolkit

Can anyone tell me what this error means exactly?

> The context of the message associated with this instance contains all the promoted properties at the time of the routing failure.

Answer (score 1):

That message got published to the message box but there were no matching subscriptions for that message (no send ports, Orchestrations or Off Ramp/Itinerary that were expecting that type of message).

Comment: ... and these are the promoted properties on which it can be routed.